# PHP error posting form data to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to make a post-ad form add data to a database. The page keeps reloading and asking to fill in all the details. I cannot seem to find the error and i have done a lot of searching on google and youtube, all to no avail. Please help!!!

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include'db.php';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['mobile-num'];
    $photos = $_POST['fileselect'];
    $town = $_POST['location'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $adTitle = $_POST['title'];
    $adDescription = $_POST['description'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {
        if($email != "" && $name != "" && $phoneNumber != "" && $photos != "" && $town != "" && $category != "" && $adTitle !="" && $adDescription != "")
        {
            $name = stripslashes($name);
            $email = stripslashes($email);
            $phoneNumber = stripslashes($phoneNumber);
            $photos = stripslashes($photos);
            $town = stripslashes($town);
            $adTitle = stripslashes($adTitle);
            $category = stripslashes($category);
            $adDescription = stripslashes($adDescription);

            $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$name);
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$email);
            $phoneNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$phoneNumber);
            $photos = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$photos);
            $town = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$town);
            $adTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$adTitle);
            $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$category);
            $adDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$adDescription);
            $imagePath = "images/".basename($_FILES['fileselect']['MAX_FILE_SIZE']);
            $photo = $_FILES['fileselect']['MAX_FILE_SIZE'];
            $date = date("j F Y");



            if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            {
                mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT email,ad-title,ad-category,ad-description,Photos,Name,Mobile-Num,Town,date from ads");
                $insertQuery = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO ads(email,ad-title,ad-category,ad-description,Photos,Name,Mobile-Num,Town,date) 
                                                            VALUES('$email','$adTitle','$category','$adDescription','$photo','$name','$phoneNumber','$town','$date')");
                header("Location: /profile.php");
            }
            else
                $_SESSION['errorMessage'] = "Please check email pattern";
                header("Location: /post-ad.php");
        }
        else
            $_SESSION['errorMessage'] = "Please input all the required details";
            header("Location: /post-ad.php");
    }
    else
        header("Location: /login.php");

?>
```

That's the PHP code. 
Since I am not very good with Stackoverflow, I am having issues formatting the html form code i wanted to post here. I will attach an image instead. [Html form code for the post-ad form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAYA8.png)

Comment: Use prepared statements and your code wil be a lot neater and shorter. To find out what the problem is remove those redirects!

Comment: so the error is validation right?

Comment: ^ This. Just comment out all the `header()`-functions and look for any error. To display SQL errors, you can add ` or die(mysqli_error());` at the end of your `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: May help... If you have PHP MyAdmin open SQL and try inserting your statement and see if it works. You can use this to trouble shoot your queries.

Comment: @e4c5 I am new to PHP. Please point me in the right direction where I can get resources for best practices. Thanks

Comment: @dekts The error is not validation. I found out the image wasn't been loaded at all from the form. Corrected that, Now working on the errors I received after commenting out the redirects.

Comment: @StuntHacks Thanks. Commenting out the redirects helped display some errors. Working on it now...

Comment: No errors found by mysql_error(). I get a blank white page with no update in the database.

Comment: that's because it should be `mysqli_error($connection)` and the hyphens in your column names; mysql thinks you want to do math and substract. Those are obvious syntax errors. See the answer below

Comment: or it never made it there to start with. Use php's error reporting

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are running the SELECT, as you seem to do nothing with it and no parameters.  But the INSERT should be...

```
$insertQuery = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO ads(email,`ad-title`,`ad-category`,`ad-description`,`Photos`,`Name`,`Mobile-Num`,`Town`,`date`) 
                                                            VALUES('$email','$adTitle','$category','$adDescription','$photo','$name','$phoneNumber','$town','$date')");
```

When you have column names with hyphens in them it should be enclosed in back-ticks, either that of I would recommend (if not tooo late ) to remove the hyphens and use an underscore instead.

You should also check for errors when running any SQL and do some sort of processing with them.

Comment: I removed the Select querry as it is not useful, removed the hyphens from the database column names both in the code and in the database itself. Still not working. I just get a blank white page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for the help. Sorry for putting you all through the stress. I went through my database structure and found a column with the wrong type that was preventing the sql insert query. My apologies....